# Models not populating with data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I recently changed my site's structure to work with two models in my view, but now my view is not populating anything. Hoping someone can help me figure out what's wrong.

Model:

```
namespace FTv2.Models
{
    public class UnitViewModel
    {
        public Unit Unit { get; set; }
        public int TradeCount { get; set; }
    }
    public class UnitViewModelDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Trade> Movies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Unit> Units { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
 var units = db.Units;
    var students = db.Units.Select(u => new UnitViewModel()
    {
        Unit = u,
        TradeCount =
               db.Movies.Where(t => t.Name == u.Name).Count()
    });
    return View(students.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

View:

```
 @model PagedList.IPagedList<FTv2.Models.UnitViewModel>

    <table style="border-width: 1px; border-color:#000000; border-style: solid; border-top: 2px; border-top-color:#000000; border-top-style: solid;">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Skill</th>
            <th>Rating</th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {

        <tr>
            <td>
                @{ ViewBag.ImgUrl = item.Name + ".png";}
                <a href="/Images/@ViewBag.ImgUrl" data-lightzap="" ><img src="/Images/@ViewBag.ImgUrl" HEIGHT="66" WIDTH="50" ></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="/ActiveTrades?Name=@item.Unit.Name">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Unit.Name)</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Unit.Type)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Unit.Skill)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Unit.Rating)
            </td>
            <td>
                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TradeCount)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
```

Thanks in advance for any help, I really appreciate it!

edit: confirmed pagedlist is the not the issue, as it persists even when returning to a normal view.

Comment: Where is ToPagedList Method?

Comment: @Anon, i don't think he passed an anonymous type.

Comment: ToPagedList is a package I added, worked fine when I was just using one model, could this be the issue?

Comment: @kgst what are the values of pageindex and pagesize?

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan they just tell the size of the page and which page to start on, page size is set to 20 and page set to one, though I don't think this is the issue as it was working before.

Comment: does students.ToPagedList return anything?

Answer (score 0):

Is UnitViewModelDBContext setup to work with your database? You can use your regular DbContext to populate the Units per your other question earlier.

Comment: Sorry I am a little confused, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

What's `modelItem`? Would using `@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.XXX)` work since the loop variable is `item`?

```
 @foreach (var item in Model) {

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Unit.Type)
        </td>
```

Comment: I'm also not sure if a href="/Images/@ViewBag.ImgUrl" will work within quotes, but I would need to go check the razor syntax again.